# Close window made with QStackedWidget

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm developing a software written in Python using the PyQT library. I want to implement an "exit" command in the File menu. The relevant part of code:

```
class Interface (QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Interface, self).__init__()
        loadUi("interface.ui", self)
        self.conectarSinais()

    def conectarSinais(self):      
        #menu
        self.actionSair.triggered.connect(self.fecharPrograma)
   
    def fecharPrograma(self):
        self.close()

 app = QApplication(sys.argv)
 JanelaPrincipal = Interface()
 widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
 widget.addWidget(JanelaPrincipal)
 widget.show()
 sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Obs: "self.actionSair" is the object name given to the action in QT Designer, where I created the "interface.ui" file. When the software runs, it shows correctly the menu and clicking it correctly calls the "fecharPrograma" slot:

File menu working:

[image: File menu working]

However, when clicking at "Sair" (exit), it seems that only QStackedWidget is closed, and a blank screen is left:
blank screen instead of closed window:

[image: blank screen instead of closed software]

How can I correctly shutdown the entire program when clicking the "Sair" (exit) menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `self.close()` on the `Interface` instance, and this is the problem when trying to use a stacked widget as "main window", as some tutorials unfortunately suggest, which is often a bad suggestion (especially if the widget that is being added is a QDialog or QMainWindow).<sup>[1]</sup>

In this case, the solution is to call `close` on the top level window:

```
    def fecharPrograma(self):
        self.window().close()
```

The reality is that the "main window" (the stacked widget) should also be a subclass that implements a signal from any of its children in order to close itself. Note that in this case I also changed the inheritance of `Interface`, since using QMainWindow for this purpose is pointless.

```
class Interface(QWidget):
    closeRequest = pyqtSignal()
    # ...
    def conectarSinais(self):      
        #menu
        self.actionSair.triggered.connect(self.closeRequest)

class MainWindow(QStackedWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.janelaPrincipal = Interface()
        self.addWidget(self.janelaPrincipal)
        self.janelaPrincipal.closeRequest.connect(self.close)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWindow = MainWindow()
mainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

<sup>[1] - I have already contacted the author of that tutorial in order to suggest *many* corrections about this and many other *wrong* suggestions provided, but unfortunately I got no response. Please be aware that while conceptually that tutorial is not *that* bad, there are many aspects and that are ignored or that create misconceptions. I suggest you to look for alternate sources.</sup>

Comment: Thank you @musicamante ! I added the ".window()" to the command and it worked fine. Now I'll try to improve the code design to adress the inheritance issue.